# Simple Question concerning the supremum of functions

Tags: real-analysis

Let us say that $x$ and $y$ belong to an interval $I$ . Assume that the function $g$ is bounded on I . is it true that $|g(x)-g(y)|$ is less than or equal to $\sup\{g(x)-g(y)\}$?? Of course this is trivial if the absolute value sign is removed ..Its seems that my Analysis book makes this assumption when proving certain facts concerning integrability but I just do not know if this is true or if it is how to prove it.....

Comment: The supremum over what?  As you've described it, neither $x$ and $y$ are free; you've identified two fixed elements of the interval $I$.

Comment: You're confused because you gave $x$ and $y$ two different roles (at first they were fixed, and now they are allowed to range over $I$.

Comment: The supremum is over the interval I.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! Note that $|g(x)-g(y)|=g(x)-g(y)$ or $g(y)-g(x)$, so $\sup_{x,y\in I}(g(x)-g(y))\geq |g(x)-g(y)|$.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer , but why is sup greater or equal to in the case of g(y)-g(x) ??

Comment: Note that $g(y)-g(x)$ is the same that $g(x)-g(y)$ with $x$ changed by $y$ and $y$ changed by $x$. In other words, $\sup_{x,y}(g(x)-g(y))$ include $g(x)-g(y)$ and $g(y)-g(x)$, i.e., $\sup_{x,y}(g(x)-g(y))\geq g(x)-g(y)$ and $\sup_{x,y}(g(x)-g(y))\geq g(y)-g(x)$.

Comment: Thanks !! I had thought about this but was not sure

Answer (score 0):

Assume there are $x_0,x_1 \in I$ such that $|g(x_0) - g(x_1)| > \sup_{x,y \in I}\{g(x)-g(y)\}$. Then $g(x_0)-g(x_1) < |g(x_0)-g(x_1)|$ and $g(x_1)-g(x_0) < |g(x_1)-g(x_0)|$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer ....Could you please explain more I still don't see it.....